# Iteratively add to sequence in for loop R

Tags: r, for-loop

I would like to iteratively add elements to a list over which I loop:

```
list = as.list(c(1,2,3))
list
for (x in list) {
  new_element = as.list(x^2)
  print(new_element)
  list = union(list, new_element)
}
list
```

However, R takes only the original 3 elements in the loop.
I would like that the loop continues with the new elements. Any ideas on how I could adjust my code? Thanks!

Comment: It isn't clear what the intended output is. Are you trying to make an infinite loop?

Comment: you loop is supposed to continue till what?

Comment: Sorry for making it not clear. This is just an example and would indeed result in an indefinite loop. In my case,  it will have an natural end because there are no more elements to add. I am scraping individuals from a datasource and want to scrape also all their siblings which are linked in the jsons of the individuals (my original list).- Is it clear now?

Comment: It might have been clearer if you had something like `if(x < 10){...}` as the body of the loop, along with an explicit intended output ((1,2,3,4,9,16,81)? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `while` loop rather than a `for` loop, together with `break` to eventually terminate:

```
mylist = as.list(c(1,2,3))
i <- 1
while(TRUE){
  x <- mylist[[i]]
  if(x<10){
    new_element <- as.list(x^2)
    print(new_element)
    mylist = union(mylist, new_element)
    i <- i+1
  } else {
    break
  }
}
```

This causes `mylist` to have 7 items (lists containing 1,2,3,4,9,16,81 respectively) when the loop terminates.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! I haven't thought about a while loop (I am very new to R) and it is clever to use the index of the list!